# hibernate secondary table for same entity relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Profile class which holds user's information. One of the features of this application is to "follow" another profiles of your choice. I'm having trouble designing the DB and making the link happen, both writing the model code and the repository (is it just a matter of a save?).

My Profile class looks like this: (irrelevant fields to the question and getters/setters are omitted for the sake of simplicity)

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Profile implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 32)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 16)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Email
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="profile_id")
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile")
    private List<Profile> friends = new ArrayList<>();


    public Profile() {
    }

    // other getters/setters

    public List<Profile> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<Profile> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public void addFriend(Profile friend) {
        this.friends.add(friend);
    }
}
```

This creates a `null` field called `profile_id` in the users' table. I've done some research and it seems like creating another table using `@SecondaryTable` annotation may do the trick. The tutorials I've looked into did not solve my doubts. I'd like some light into the matter, and if possible avoid creating a different entity.

Ideally, I'd have a table with its own id, the owner's id (the person who is following) and the target's id (the person who is being followed).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a problem on having a null field called profile_id, and actually this is the way how it should behave. But I do think your problem is in the entity relationship concept. From what I can imagine I think you might need a ManyToMany relationship. One user might have multiple followers, and one follower(user)  might be following multiple users.

Comment: @ShpendPalushi I think you're right. Still a beginner with databases here. Can you add something to Ken Chan's answer? Looks promessing to me but raises an exception during initialization. Thanks

Comment: Let me post an detailed answer about your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a separate table to store this following relationship (many-to-many). The most simplest way is to use `@ManyToMany` :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Profile implements Serializable {


        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="following", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="follower_id")})
        private Set<Profile> followers = new HashSet<Profile>();

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Profile> followBy = new HashSet<Profile>();
}
```

It will be mapped to a relationship table called `following` which has the following schema :

```
---------------------------------
| column      | FK              |
=================================
| user_id     | FK to users.id  |
---------------------------------
| follower_id | FK to users.id  |
---------------------------------
```

So given an user A , the field `followers` is all users that A is following to. And the field `followBy` is all users the are following to A.

Also , note that the `mappedBy` setting .It means you have to use the field `followers` to maintain this following relationship but not the field `followBy`, which basically means that you have to insert /remove instances to the `followers` Set to change the following relationship for a given profile.

Also see [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) if you want the add additional columns to the relationship table (i.e. `following` table)

Comment: I actually understood what you did there and makes sense to me. However, implementing it on code and running the server raises an exception during initialization: ```org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn``` This points to the followers set.

Comment: then remove one the @JoinTable in one of the field , see my update and let me know if it works

Comment: I actually made it work simply removing the mappedBy attribute. Is it harmful performance-wise? I'm marking this answer as accepted nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

Well, implementing a `@ManyToMany` relationship has two approaches. First is to create a separate table only with the respective Id's of each entity. And that thing, might be easy, but it does not cover all the cases. For example in your case you are implementing a `@ManyToMany` for user and followers. You also might need a date for that,to show in which date they created that relationship. And that is the case where the things get a little bit complicated(not much), but it results in a piece of beauty code. Anyways let's go for both approaches:

`

```
  @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "profile_follower", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName="id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "following_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Set<Profile> profiles;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "profiles")
    private Set<Profile> following= new HashSet<>();
```

`

The other approach is creating a separate class for the relationship.
`

```
@Entity
public class ProfilesFollowedByUser{
@EmbeddedId
UserFollower id;//this is a separate class

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("id")
@JoinColumn(name="profile_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Profile profile;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("id")
@JoinColumn(name="following_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Profile profile;

private Date createdAt;}
```

`
And here is the embeddable class:

`

```
@Embeddable
public class UserFollower implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 819015237657421374L;

    @Column(name="profile_id")
    private Long profileId;
    @Column(name="following_id")
    private Long followingId;
}
```

`
The second one is probably a little bit more complicated but in vast majority of scenarios at least in the real world apps, when you have to deal with a relationship created a date at least is always needed. Hope that helps with your problem.